# AQUA, permission denied

Tags: linux, permission-denied

I am trying to compile the alignment program AQUA with a .tcl script. I have compiled the programs and set the environmental variables in the .tcl file but I am still getting the following error;

> tclsh AQUA.tcl mtDNA.fas
>   stderr couldn't execute "/home/shump/AQUA/muscle": permission denied
>   couldn't execute "/home/shump/AQUA/rascal": permission denied
>   couldn't execute "/home/shump/AQUA/normd": permission denied
>   One normd file does not exists yet (mtDNA.fas.muscle.normd), full stop

If anyone could put me in the right direction to solve this issue, I would appreciate it.

P

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to set the execute bit permission on the files mentioned, using:

```
chmod +x /home/shump/AQUA/muscle /home/shump/AQUA/rascal /home/shump/AQUA/normd
```

Comment: No that didn't seem to work, I also tried chmod 777 but nothing.